# How to initialize an m*n matrix in R with specific row and column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to initialize a m*n matrix in R.
Let's say I have a seq of variable names `c(a, b, c, d)`, and I would like to create a 4*10 matrix with `c(a, b, c, d)` being the vertical variable, and `seq(1:10)` to be horizontal variable, so I can check the matrix with the call `matrix[a, 1]`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create the `matrix` as

```
m1 <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 10, dimnames = list(letters[1:4], NULL))
```

and use the row names and column index to extract elements

```
m1['a', 1]
```

Comment: Note dimensions are reversed.  Also need to add values `m1 <- matrix(seq(1, 10)...)`

Comment: @SteveM It is not clear because of `matrix[a, 1]` in the OP's post.  Regarding the values, I am not sure whether they need a NA matrix or the sequence.  I am thinking that the seq(1, 10), is the column names

Comment: Right, I see. He specifies a:d as rows  But also "variable names".  So 4 X 10 is probably his error.

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `row.names<-`

```
`row.names<-`(matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 10), head(letters, 4))
```